# WebSockets connection scalability

Tags: support, statistics

I was wondering with so many users connected to StackOverflow, how is scalability of WebSockets connections issue resolved?

I am interested from both perspectives of number of users that need to get specific data (for their threads, answers etc). As well as how so much data is categorised so fast to allow it to still be delivered live to user.

Comment: Keep in mind the alternative is thousands of people sitting there mashing refresh to see the newest content, so it needs to be better than *that*, rather than being better than not communicating with those clients.

Comment: If you throw enough server resources at it, anything will work..